# How to whitelist multiple domains phonegap (cordova)

Tags: cordova

How can I list multiple domains? I know how to whitelist one with all it's subdomains, but what if I need more than one? Add more access elements?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [Cordova docs](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.5.0/guide_appdev_whitelist_index.md.html) refer to the [Widget Access specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/widgets-access/#the-access-element), which states:

> Zero or more access elements can be placed in the configuration document. When multiple access elements are used by an author, the set of network connections that are allowed is the union of all the access requests that were granted by the user agent.

In other words, just include multiple elements:

```
<access origin="http://example.net"/>
<access origin="http://another_example.net"/>
```

Comment: How to whitelist youtube ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, here you have an example:

http://cartografia.cime.es/WebEditor/Pagines/file/tallerPhoneGap/index.html#build